# How To Create Particle Collision Effect?

Tags: animation, node-editor, particles

Is there a way to keyframe the scale of the objects inside blender particle system while still letting the objects collide with each other like the example beneath?

I have already tried the blender molecular add-on to keyframe the scale of the objects. But the problem is that when I keyframe the scale, the colliding of the objects gets disabled.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Gv9HxS_s-Y&t=38s&ab_channel=zuggamasta

Comment: Please don't ask a question that rely only on an external link.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While images and links are helpful additions, questions should stand on their own. [Please provide some context and explanation, don't just post an image or link](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: hi, sorry for that! i have edited the post again.